# when I try to login Privateroute not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create an admin login where after I log in  I will get dashboard client and product pages but when I use the privateroute it is not working properly but I am not able to login and also when I try to access client and product I am not able to access them I am using firebase to login and authentication

This is my app.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import AdminLogin from "./admin/AdminLogin";
import AdminDashboard from "./admin/AdminDashboard";
import MainSection from "./components/MainSection";
import CustomerForm from "./components/CustomerForm";
import { AuthProvider, useAuth } from "./context/AuthContext";
import PrivateRoute from "./routes/PrivateRoute";

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<AdminLogin />} />
          <Route
            path="/dashboard"
            element={
              <PrivateRoute>
                <AdminDashboard />
              </PrivateRoute>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/client"
            element={
              <PrivateRoute>
                <MainSection />
              </PrivateRoute>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/product"
            element={
              <PrivateRoute>
                <CustomerForm />
              </PrivateRoute>
            }
          />
        </Routes> 
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
} 

export default App;
```

this is AuthContext

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { auth } from "../firebase"; // Import Firebase authentication

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user); // Set current user based on Firebase authentication state
    });

    return unsubscribe; // Cleanup function
  }, []);

  const login = (email, password) => {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    return auth.signOut();
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

AdminLogin

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"; // Import useNavigate
import { auth } from "../firebase";
// import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";

const AdminLogin = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [prevAuthState, setPrevAuthState] = useState(false); // Previous authentication state

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setLoading(false);
      if (user && prevAuthState) {
        alert("you are already logged in");
        navigate("/dashboard"); // Redirect to dashboard if user is already logged in
      }
      setPrevAuthState(!!user); // Update previous authentication state
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [navigate, prevAuthState]);

  const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      navigate("/dashboard");
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>; // Render loading indicator
  }
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-50 py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div className="max-w-md w-full space-y-8">
        <div>
          <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">
            Admin Login
          </h2>
        </div>
        <form className="mt-8 space-y-6" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
          <input
            type="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            required
            className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-t-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
            placeholder="Email address"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
            required
            className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-b-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
            placeholder="Password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
            <div className="text-sm">
              <p className="text-red-500">{error}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
            >
              Sign in
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AdminLogin;
```

this is AdminDashboard

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, Route, Routes, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import MainSection from "../components/MainSection"; // Import Client component
// import ProductComponent from "./ProductComponent"; // Import Product component

const AdminDashboard = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // Loading state
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null); // User state

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if user is authenticated
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setLoading(false); // Update loading state
      setUser(user); // Update user state
      if (!user) {
        navigate("/"); // Redirect to login page if not logged in
      }
    });

    // Cleanup function
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [navigate]);

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      await auth.signOut();
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error signing out:", error);
    }
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>; // Render loading indicator
  }

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-50 py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div className="max-w-md w-full space-y-8">
        <div>
          <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">
            Welcome to Admin Dashboard
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
          <button
            onClick={handleLogout}
            className="group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-red-500"
          >
            Logout
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-4 space-y-4">
          <Link
            to="/client"
            className="group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
          >
            Client
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AdminDashboard;
```

this is privateroute

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../context/AuthContext";

const PrivateRoute = ({ element, ...rest }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();

  return isAuthenticated ? (
    <Route {...rest} element={element} />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/" replace />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `useAuth()` never shares a value named `isAuthenticated` so your code for `PrivateRoute` will always simply navigate to `/`.

Comment: thanks, bro! this also helped me but the main cause  was that I was using route instead of outlet